# How to get HTTP status in advice recovery callback

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a simple integration flow which sends request to an external resource with several attempts. I am creating `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` for this purpose:

```
RequestHandlerRetryAdvice requestHandlerRetryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
requestHandlerRetryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(retryContext -> {
    Message<?> failedMessage = ((MessagingException) retryContext.getLastThrowable()).getFailedMessage();
    //TODO: get http status
    return failedMessage.getPayload();
});
```

What I need to know is the http status. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP Status is a part of a thrown exception:

`((MessagingException) retryContext.getLastThrowable()).getCause()`  should contain an `HttpStatusCodeException` with the `getStatusCode()` property.

My tests shows this:

```
retryContext = ...
 lastException = org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: ...
  failedMessage = ...
  backtrace = {Object[6]@7673} 
  detailMessage = "Failed to handle"
  cause = org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ...
   failedMessage = ...
   cause = {HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden@7685} "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [no body]"
    statusCode = {HttpStatus@7690} "403 FORBIDDEN"
    rawStatusCode = 403
    statusText = "Forbidden"
```

The code is like this:

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway("/service/internal?{params}")
                                .uriVariable("params", "payload")
                                .expectedResponseType(String.class),
                        e ->  e.advice(retryAdvice()))

private RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice() {
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice requestHandlerRetryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        requestHandlerRetryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(retryContext -> {
            MessagingException lastThrowable = (MessagingException) retryContext.getLastThrowable();
            return ((HttpStatusCodeException) lastThrowable.getCause().getCause()).getStatusCode();
        });
        return requestHandlerRetryAdvice;
    }
```

Comment: In my case it's `MessageHandlingException`.

Comment: `.getCause().getCause()` then?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no `HttpStatusCodeException` at any level.

Comment: Please, see an edit in my answer. Are you sure that you really talk about an HTTP call from your code?