# Taking an action when HTTP response status is not 200

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm new to Spring Integration. I have a simple flow which send request to external resource with several attemps.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(MY_CHANNEL)
    .handle(myOutboundGateway, e -> e.advice(myRetryAdvice))
    .wireTap(logResponse())
    .get();
```

What I need to do is to take some action (saving data to a database) when calling external resource (after retrying) is not succesful (http status code is not 200 OK). How can I achieve that in my flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all the attempts of the retry are exhausted, the `RecoveryCallback` is called.
See some sample here: [How to get HTTP status in advice recovery callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022690/how-to-get-http-status-in-advice-recovery-callback). In that `RecoveryCallback` you can just return `null` and send a message to some channel for that storing to DB logic.

Another way is to have extra advice on top of that retry instead of `RecoveryCallback`. See its docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice. This way when all the attempts are done, the exception is going to be bubbled and caught by that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and its `failureChannel`. Pay attention to the `trapException = true`, so the error doesn't go back to the flow. Only to that `failureChannel` for your DB logic.